# Which type of feature extractor do you suggest to classify sensor data?

Tags: classification, autoencoders, time-series, feature-extraction, signal-processing

I have IMU (Inertial Measurment Unit- 6 axis) sensor data. The sensor attached on a car and 7 different drivers wipe on same path. I want to extract features and classify drivers. Which type of feature extractor do you guys suggest? I am planning to use PCA and Autoencoders but what do you think about classical signal properties to classify drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple possible ways to extract the features. One would be to use RNNs for a temporal relationship as the input data is time-series.